# Find all nodes that DON'T have NoSchedule taint?

Tags: kubernetes

What is `kubectl` command that lists all nodes that **don't have** `NoSchedule` taint(s)?

What is `kubectl` command that lists all nodes that **do have**  `NoSchedule` taint(s)?

Answer (score 4):

You could get nodes and taints with using `jsonpath`.

```
 kubectl get node -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}{"\t"}{@.spec.taints[*].effect}{"\n"}{end}'
```

Have NoSchedule

```
 kubectl get node -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}{"\t"}{@.spec.taints[*].effect}{"\n"}{end}' | grep NoSchedule
```

Don't Have NoSchedule

```
 kubectl get node -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}{"\t"}{@.spec.taints[*].effect}{"\n"}{end}' | grep -v NoSchedule
```